# add and remove to favorite function in jquery mobile and view favorited items in separate listview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

i am developing an android app using Apache Cordova/Phonegap and Jquery Mobile that consists of fashion items like woman shoes, purses, clothes, etc... and I would like to add a button that allows users to add favorite items and that those added items can be viewed in a separate listview page within the app itself and that also users are able to remove these favorited items when they don´t want them as favorites anymore... This is a very important feature for any app that sell different type of products and for user experience as well.

I have added a few screen shots of what I think would be the workflow of what I am trying to get reference on. If any of you guys have implemented such functions, please let know how I can go about it... your help will be greatly appreciated.

ITEM ON APP:

[image: Screenshot1]

APP MENU:

[image]

FAVORITES ITEM PAGE ON APP:

[image]

ITEM DETAIL VIEW PAGE:

[image]

Comment: I have implemented something similar in an HTML5 application. Fav icon clicks are sent to the dbase with ajax. A separate table in the dbase links article number and user ID. The icon is updated accordingly. The listview is generated from a db-query specific on user's favorites

Comment: Hi Gdahl, Thanks for replying... Can you please show me a sample of what you implemented... Thank you

Comment: The app is not open for the public. If you do have any specific questions in mind, please ask.

Comment: For reference, you could also look to the function "favorite question" in these forums.

Comment: What do you mean The App is not open for the public?

Comment: What is there to mean? The application is running on a protected server that I cannot give you access to. If you're looking for complete code to copy/paste, I cannot help you. If you have specific questions related to the relevant languages (HTML/js/Ajax/php/SQL) I might be able to help you.

Comment: I understand your point. But I am not asking for a complete copy/paste solution. What I need is just an insight of how the function should be structured for this to work. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Folks, Any Idea on how to implement this on Cordova/Phonegap App using jquery mobile...Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You ask me to check your question. Yeah its easy to achieve, all you need to do is enable local storage in your Android App, and then use javascript to save/read/delete local-storage items. The items will  be the users favorites. You can do anything with that data. --- check this demo --- http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/7/13/jQuery-Mobile--adding-Local-Storage

Comment: Thank you!!! Tasos..! This is the way to go!! Let me know if you have twitter account to follow you as well. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

This could take any number of forms, since the question is not clear.

However, my guess is your best bet would be to simply add a value to localStorage via javascript that identifies the given item as vbeing a favourite eg:

```
localStorage.Favourites = 'itemID';
```

You would probably want to have more than 1 favourite(s) so you should probably make this a string with a delimiter such a:

```
localSotrage.Favourites += 'itemID,';
```

Then on each product detail page, split the string value in localStorage.Favourites and check if the id of the current product is in that.